# chrome extension notification onclick event action based on type of notification

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have two different functions that creates a chrome.notification and I would like the onclick actions to be separate as well. When I browse through the chrome extension API, there isn't a mention of how to handle this situation.

Here is the code I have in my background.js

```
chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(event){
  chrome.tabs.create({url: 'details.html?id=' + event});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a different id to each notification and check that id in the [listener function](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#event-onClicked):

```
chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notifId){
    if (notifId == "notification_1") {
        //handle notification 1 being clicked
    }
    if (notifId == "notification_2") {
        //handle notification 2 being clicked
    }
    //etc.
});
```